# setting element of array to zero in assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86

hi I have this data `arr1 WORD 1234h, 0abh, 5678h`, I am trying to set the last 2 elements of this array to 0 so I did this `mov BYTE PTR edi+2, 0`, however I get an error saying invalid use of register, why did this eror show up, I did the same thing with the memory operand and there was no error

thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention which assembler you're using, but based on your use of `BYTE PTR` I'm going to assume TASM or MASM.

Your array is an array of words, so to set the last 2 elements to zero you need to write 2 words (or 1 dword), rather than 1 byte like you're trying to do.

This ought to work (assuming that `EDI` contains the address of `arr1`):

```
mov word ptr [edi+2],0
mov word ptr [edi+4],0
```

or

```
mov dword ptr [edi+2],0
```

Comment: ah thank, I was thinking that i should use word instead of byte